# jQuery toggle not working on iPhone8 or other iOS devices

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle, responsive

Hey guys I have a header that when on a small screen shows a hamburger menu. When I click on the hamburger menu on the PC or on an Android phone it does exactly what I want it to do but when I do it on iOS on my iPhone 8 it doesn't do anything. I have put an alert in there to see if it is even recognizing my touch and it does using $(".myMenu").click(function(){alert("clicked div");}); . But I have tried slideToggle, toggle, and hide/show and none of them work and it only has the issue on iOS. I was reading other forums and someone said to surround it in anchor tags and that didn't work. Others said that I need to set the css to cursor:pointer and that didn't work. Someone suggested clearing cache on the browser and that didn't work. I found other CDNs on github that fixes the issue and that didn't work. I read there was a problem with ajax so it needed to be set to false which is highlighted in my code below and that didn't work. The last piece of advice I found was to ensure that display was set to block and that didn't work. I am probably using more CDN's than I need but at this point I have just been adding the ones I think are relevant to see if they do anything. I have looked as much as I can and I don't know where else to turn to. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my jsfiddle......https://jsfiddle.net/62pmq7ju/9/

```
<div class="header">

<a><div><img src="img/icon.png" alt="" width="40px" height="45px" class="myMenu"/></div></a>
<div class="hiddenMenu"></div>
</div>

.hiddenMenu {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
background-image: url(img/headerBackground.jpg);
top:45px;
display: block;
cursor: pointer;
}

.myMenu {
position: relative;
float: left;
padding-left: 5px;
display: block;
cursor: pointer;
}

    <script>
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    // jQuery Mobile's Ajax navigation does not work in all cases (e.g.,
    // when navigating from a mobile to a non-mobile page), especially when going back, hence disabling it.
    $.extend($.mobile, {
        ajaxEnabled: false
    });
    }); 
    $(".hiddenMenu").hide();
    $(".myMenu").on("click", function(){
       $(".hiddenMenu").toggle(); 
    });
    </script>
```

The jsfiddle doesn't work on chrome or safari on my iOS devices but it does on my android device and widows laptop. Please any help would be appreciated, I have been working on this for the last three days and I don't know where else to look. If I am missing something in my post I apologize and let me know what you need.

Comment: a dumb question...
can you see the menu when you put it in display block? if the event is firing then its probably a CSS issue...

Comment: yes I can see it. I can see it on the iPhone it just do anything when i touch it. The alert works but nothing else. It works perfectly on my Android phone though

Comment: I meant the menu... I tried to see the menu using chrome (in iPhone 8 mode), I saw that the element is changing but still not visible...

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/)) {

    
    $('.head_download').on('click', function(){
$('.f_list_season').removeClass('show');
$(this).addClass('show');
});
}
```

Here is your example:

```
       if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/)) {
        $('.header img').on('click', function(){
             $('.hiddenMenu').removeAttr('style');
             $(this).css("display", "none");
                });
         }
```